# .htaccess Doesn't Show in Nitrous Container

Tags: html, .htaccess, nitrousio

We added a .htaccess file in our Node.js Nitrous Container, but it doesn't appear in our list of files, so we can't edit it and it doesn't work.  When we try to make a new one, it says there is already a file with that name.  Any ideas why this is or how to fix it?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to view hidden files on [Nitrous](https://www.nitrous.io):

1. Select the "**Show hidden files**" menu item from the file tree dropdown menu. The files should appear in your the tree and you can select and edit them.

[image: Nitrous Show Hidden Files]

2. In the Nitrous console, write `ls -a` to show hidden files. You can edit the file using emacs or vim via the console.